# "Mi sarei aspettata" versus "mi sarei aspettato"

Tags: past-participle, gender

What is the correct way to write the following sentence, when said by a woman?

> Non mi sarei aspettato di ricevere un tuo SMS.

I am not sure it should be *sarei aspettata* or *sarei aspettato*. My thought is that the sentence would mean *ricevere un tuo SMS non era qualcosa di aspettato*; therefore, it should be *sarei aspettato* even when the sentence is uttered by a woman.

Comment: kiam, se una donna dicesse '... non mi sarei *accorto* di ricevere ...' si potrebbe avere l'impressione di sentir parlare un transessuale. Sicché, per analogia, inferisco che sia corretto usare il femminile 'aspettata', though. Cioè, non capisco come in un caso dovresti usare 'accorta' e nell'altro 'aspettato', anyway.

Comment: The participle is referred to the subject; when the verb is in medial form (*aspettarsi*) it must be declined with the gender of the subject; if plural it would be *non ci saremmo aspettati* or *aspettate*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The past participle, when used as an adjective, must agree in gender and number with the noun it refers to, so

> Lei disse: "Mi sarei aspettata di ricevere un tuo SMS!"
>
> I miei amici si sarebbero aspettati di sentirti.
>
> Le mie nipoti si sarebbero aspettate ben altre cose.
>
> Io, come uomo, mi sarei aspettato tu usassi il genere corretto nel participio

What makes it confusing is that the verb is reflexive. Surely there's no doubt when using an active verb:

> Lei disse: "Sarei andata al ristorante"

Comment: I wouldn't call *aspettarsi* a reflexive verb.

Comment: it [is](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/aspettare.shtml)

Comment: Would you call reflexive the verb in *mi sono mangiato una mela*? If you do, then also *aspettarsi* is reflexive. ;-)

Comment: I don't argue with dictionaries... :) the above comment is a link to a definition.

Comment: I won't argue either. But I prefer to call it a “medial” verb (and I'm not alone). They share the form, not the meaning. Pedantry, maybe.